# Flutter pub get error due to Dark SDK version or flutter_launcher_name

Tags: flutter, dart, null-safety

I wanted to use `pub get` using Flutter, and I encountered this error:

```
C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get
Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 3.0.0-417.0.dev.

Because flutter_launcher_name 0.0.1 doesn't support null safety and no versions of flutter_launcher_name match >0.0.1 <0.1.0, flutter_launcher_name ^0.0.1 is forbidden.
So, because qed_app_thinkit depends on flutter_launcher_name ^0.0.1, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.1.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I don't know what to do. the result of `flutter doctor` was normal, and I tried Flutter Update, flutter clean, etc.
What is the problem?

working `pub get` properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is very clear: it says `flutter_launcher_name` doesn't support null-safety. Check out your plugin version, it is written in 3 years ago. Please use other plugin.

Edit: I don't know why you need to use this plugin, you can easily change your app name at `MaterialApp`

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use `non-null-safe` packages in `null-safe` projects. While it may be technically possible to do so, it can introduce potential issues into your codebase, and it may be difficult to maintain in the long term.

Here is a tutorial that you can use to change the application name:

[Change Application Name and Icon in Flutter project(Android and iOS)](https://medium.com/@vaibhavi.rana99/change-application-name-and-icon-in-flutter-bebbec297c57)

In addition, you can take a look at this thread:

[Use a non-null safety package inside a null safety enabled app dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68518068/use-a-non-null-saftey-package-inside-a-null-saftey-enabled-app-dart)